# ZeroMQ REQ/REP server error handling

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying to use the ZeroMQ rep/req and cannot figure out how to handle server side errors. Look at the code from [here](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html):

```
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)
while True:
    #  Wait for next request from client
    message = socket.recv()
    print "Received request: ", message
    time.sleep (1)  
    socket.send("World from %s" % port)
```

My problem is what happens if the client calls socket.send() and then hangs or crashes. Wouldn't the server just get stuck on socket.send() or socket.recv() forever?

Note that it is not a problem with TCP sockets. With TCP sockets I can simply break the connection. With ZMQ, the connections are implicitly managed for me and I don't know if it is possible to break a 'session' or 'connection' and start over.

Answer (score 6):

You can terminate ZMQ sockets much the same way you terminate TCP sockets.

`socket.close()`

If you need to wait on a message but only up for a finite amount of time you can pass a `timeout` flag to `socket.recv(timeout=1024)` and then handle the timeout error case the same way you would when a TCP socket timeouts or disconnects. If you need to manage several sockets all of which may be in an error state then the [`Poller`](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html#zmq.Poller) class will let you accomplish this.

Comment: On the server side, if I do socket.close(), do I close the session corresponding to THE instance of the client or do I close every session, or do I close the listening socket?

Comment: Depends on the socket class, there's different behaviors for REQ/REP vs PUB/SUB etc.

Comment: I am only interested in the REP socket.

Comment: I was wondering about this, too.  I modified the "lazy pirate server" example mentioned below, and found that the server seems not to have an issue if the client dies.  So, thankfully, there seems to be no issue, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

The ZMQ [Z-guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall) offers lots of good hints on how to structure your services to handle different scenarios.

I think [chapter 4](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Chapter-Reliable-Request-Reply-Patterns) can be of interest to you, especially the Lazy Pirate Pattern.

Check out the examples of [Lazy Pirate Server](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py%3alpserver) and [Lazy Pirate Client](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py%3alpclient).

Comment: I read those. They offer client side reliability. My problem is simpler. I just want to make sure the REP server does not get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In general,

1. Make sure you `setsockopt()` on the socket such that `send` and `recv` will not block forever. (Temporary blocking – be it client or server – is OK, but infinite blocking is bad because your application cannot do anything else)
2. In the event that any of the I/O got an error,

   - If you are the client, `close()` the current socket and re-create a new one to establish a new connection
   - If you are the server, there's nothing else to do, you simply are waiting for a new connection. You will want to explore the [Poller](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/multisocket/zmqpoller.html) class.